# Dot product between rows of two matrices with same batch dimension

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have two 2-dimensional tensors with the same batch dimension (that is, same number of rows).

```py
import numpy as np

# Both t1 and t2 have shape (2, 3)

t1 = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]])
# array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
#        [10., 11., 12.]])

t2 = np.array([[21.0, 22.0, 23.0], [30.0, 31.0, 32.0]])
# array([[21., 22., 23.],
#        [30., 31., 32.]])
```

How do I compute the dot product between the rows of the two tensors? Specifically, I want to end up with the desired (2, 1) tensor result:

```py
desired_result = np.array([np.dot(t1[0], t2[0]), np.dot(t1[1], t2[1])])
# array([ 134., 1025.])
```

I already tried:

```py
np.dot(t1, t2)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot
# ValueError: shapes (2,3) and (2,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

np.tensordot(t1, t2)
# array(1159.)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both `t1` and `t2` are 2d arrays, `numpy.dot` does [matrix multiplication](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html). For your case, you can just multiply the two arrays element wise and then sum rows:

```
(t1 * t2).sum(axis=1)
# [ 134. 1025.]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using einsum:

```
np.einsum("ij,ij->i", t1, t2)
```

Comment: Documentation says: `Evaluates the Einstein summation convention on the operands.` Wow. I have never heard of that operation.

Answer (score 0):

`np.matmul/@` does batched `dot`, but the batch dimension is first of 3 (or more).  So we have to expand the arrays:

```
In [36]: t1[:,None,:]@t2[:,:,None]
Out[36]: 
array([[[ 134.]],

       [[1025.]]])
In [37]: _.shape
Out[37]: (2, 1, 1)
```

and then squeeze out the extra dimension(s)

`matmul` is fast, but for this task the other answers might be clearer.